# Google Chrome Screen Reader App or Extension for Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am looking for a screen reader app or extension for the Google Chrome browser. This is specifically for Chrome OS so Java applets aren't an option, although Flash should be fine.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: Sometime in the last few days Chrome OS got an update to the accessibility features that includes screen reading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about recommending apps/browser extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked these accessibility extensions?

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/featured/accessibility?hl=en

According to [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-os-discuss/browse_thread/thread/37b605460bf670c2/b347547f683100fa?pli=1), development for a screen reader is underway.

Comment: I had not seen that discussion. Maybe that's the "GoogleVox" that I saw mentioned on one of the help pages, but doesn't seem to exist otherwise. I have looked at a number of other extensions, but none offer screen reading. It isn't accessibility per se that I am after. I am participating in the Cr-48 pilot program and wanted to see if screen reading was a feature currently available. Thanks!